# Computing SonarQube views with Ant

Tags: ant, sonarqube

We are using the [sonarqube ant task](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Ant) ant task to perform analysis for projects. We are also using [views](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Views+Plugin) to group projects. To [populate views](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Views+Plugin#ViewsPlugin-ComputingViews), one must call `sonar-scanner views`. Is there a way to do this also with the ant task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Views, this means that you have purchased a license so you benefit from the commercial support. So please ask this question to the person who is in contact with SonarSource support - or send a message through http://www.sonarsource.com/get-contact/.